# What does passport authenticate do on callback?

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am using passport js in my express project. The first route below goes and creates the user in my DB and then returns to the second callback route.

What is the passport.authenticate('facebook'... ) doing in the callback router?

If I I am using this in a restful API (no session), can leave out the passport.authenticate in the callback?

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/',
                                      failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the passport.authenticate('facebook'... ) doing in the
>   callback router?

That is required so that Facebook redirect the user back after approval. If you remove that, then after user authenticate with Facebook there won't get redirected to your site and/or the user authenticating would simply see an error.

> If I I am using this in a restful API (no session), can leave out the
>   passport.authenticate in the callback?

According to the passport.js [documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs/facebook) if you wish to do Facebook authentication then you need the following routes:

```
//to send user to facebook
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

//this for facebook to return user back with token, refreshToken, Profile
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/',
                                      failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

> What does passport authenticate do on callback?

The verify callback for Facebook authentication accepts `accessToken`, `refreshToken`, and `profile` arguments. profile will contain user profile information provided by Facebook.

The passport.js documentation is very good source of how things work. There are also tutorials that show you how the FB authentication workflow take place.